# Can't insert to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to insert data from my android application, but my android still can't insert to database mysql. whats wrong with my php code?

```
<?php

define('HOST','mysql.idhostinger.com');
define('USER','*********');
define('PASS','*********');
define('DB','**********');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

// Inisiasi Variable
$result = "";
if (isset($_POST['nama'])&&($_POST['email'])){
$username = $_POST['nama'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO register(username, email, tanggal_lahir, password) VALUE($username, $email, $tanggal, $password)';
if($con->query($query)){
echo "Sukses";
}
else {
echo "Gagal";
}
?>
```

Comment: change VALUE to  VALUES

Comment: i want to insert into mysql server @Divyesh

Comment: why `android` tag is here, remove it. This is not android question

Comment: your query is in wrong format

Comment: use query with double quote like $query = "INSERT INTO register(username, email, tanggal_lahir, password) VALUE($username, $email, $tanggal, $password)";

Comment: Try - "INSERT INTO register(username, email, tanggal_lahir, password) VALUES('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$tanggal."', '".$password."')";

Comment: still same. i dont have the code.

Comment: echo something inside if($con->query($query)){ and else and try to see in which condition its going. also display error in your else condition to get idea which kind of issue there like echo mysqli_error();

Comment: Can you please show the error

Comment: @Divyesh RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html `{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...` - Both `VALUE` and `VALUES` are valid in MySQL.

Comment: @Rupal *"use query with double quote like $query"* - what difference would that possibly make?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you are using any php variable inside " (double quote) then php will parse it and use the value set in that variable while if you use ' (single quote) then any PHP variable inside it, will be consider as "string". so if $test = 'abc'; and you do echo "my $test"; then it will display "my abc" but if you do echo 'my $test'; then it will display you "my $test". there are many tutorial you may find for this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
define('HOST','mysql.idhostinger.com');
define('USER','*********');
define('PASS','*********');
define('DB','**********');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

// Inisiasi Variable
$result = "";
if (isset($_POST['nama'])&&($_POST['email'])){
$username = $_POST['nama'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
}

//This seems wrong approch this code you should write inside above if condition
//What if user didn't entered email and name will you insert blank values?

$query = "INSERT INTO register(username, email, tanggal_lahir, password) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$tanggal."', '".$password."')";
if($con->query($query)){
echo "Sukses";
}
else {
echo "Gagal";
}
```

Comment: maybe, my android code is wrong. i will ask in another question, thank you

Comment: I'll bet you (also) went and posted your answer based on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436809/cant-insert-to-database#comment70079565_41436809). Read [my reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436809/cant-insert-to-database#comment70093395_41436809) to it. Just because that comment received upvotes doesn't mean it's correct and the ones who upvoted that, don't know MySQL.

Comment: @Fred-ii- In this kinda questions no one needs to see comments it's simple to answer and literally I didn't even show your comments my another purpose to post this as an answer was he was going with wrong approach as I mentioned in code with comment. I am sorry if you felt that I copied answer you gave in comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I gave the answer before you commented so there is no chance to copy anything.

Comment: @Akshay Look at the variables in the values; what's missing? Hint: they're string literals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `INSERT INTO register(`username`, `email`, `tanggal_lahir`, `password`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$email."', '".$tanggal."', '".$password."')";`

Comment: @Akshay exactly. ;-) and you need to edit your answer using that syntax.

Comment: BTW Thanks Edited @Fred-ii- :D

Answer (score -1):

I see you are not allowing any headers in your php api. Try adding these headers to the top of your PHP script

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

Comment: after i adding headers on my php, my android not respond for click. but thanks for your answer

Comment: @DennyKurniawan Are you sure there are not any syntax error. Try adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: thanks for your answer, now problem solved. i am just adding 
$query = 'INSERT INTO register(username,email,tanggal_lahir,password) VALUES($username,$email,$tanggal,$password)';